# Is there an electronic reason to make micro USB cable without data wires?

Tags: power-supply, usb, cables, wire, usb-device

When buying electronic products that use a microUSB plug for powering, we often receive a `male USB <--> male micro USB` charging cable that doesn't include the 2 DATA lines (Data + / Data -).

[image]

It's extremely annoying for the end-consumer, because :

- at the end you have a big amount of USB-µUSB cables at home **that you cannot distinguish visually (no distinctive symbol on the cable)**: some of them are "power only" (won't work to transfer files from phone to computer for example), some others "power+data"  (will work for file transfer).
- it can lead to ambiguous situations like *"My device X doesn't work anymore. I plugged it to my computer and it's not recognized as an USB device"*. In fact it's just that the cable is not a real USB cable, but only a charging cable.

**Question: Is there an electronic justification to produce micro-USB to USB cables that don't include the data lines**, except for saving 0.00001$ per cable for the maker because they can avoid 4 soldering points for the soldering robot?

Comment: Why would a manufacturer need more reason than to save some money?

Comment: Is saving 0.00001$ per cable (ok I created this number) a good reason to break something considered as a standard, and that consumers do like? 
I don't know any user that likes to have to distinguish his USB cables into 2 categories. (I just did now with a permanent marker)

Comment: If they can make more money, why would they care about whether the user like it or not? Nobody will base their buying decisions on the type of cable that comes with the device. Also note that per gram copper you save ~.5¢

Comment: Margins are *tiny* in mass-produced commodity products like this. That's also why the cable is so short.

Comment: I've already got tape on my micro and mini cables to distinguish them without having to look too hard, another different colour for non-data micro would work.

Comment: Is this actually a question or just a rant about cost cutting practices? VTC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here to hear rants about cost cutting practices.

Comment: @pjc50 the cable is short due to it  being sold with usb power banks. Bulky cables aren't very pocket friendly.

Comment: @Basj The usb standard was never originally intended to be a power only spec. There is nothing preventing people from building a non standard cable.

Comment: @Passerby, a non-compliant cable is not allowed to have the trademarked USB logo. The one in OP's picture does have the logo (at least, something close enough to cause confusion in the mind of the average consumer). Is the cable in the picture actually compliant? Hard to tell over the Internet.

Comment: @thephoton if everyone followed the money hungry usb if rules,  we would still be stuck with slow charging and no hobbyist culture

Comment: @thephoton but what does that have to do with the cable being short for practical purposes??

Comment: @Passerby, Not sure why I @'d you. It's nothing to do with the length of the cable. It's about a cable with no data wires.

Comment: This question is not a rant about cost cutting practices, I wanted to know if there are electronic reasons to do that. There *could* be some reasons. Example: 1) remove data lines to prevent the computer to say "Unknown USB device"   2) remove the data lines that would be too close of high amperage power cables (higher than the standard 0.5A for certain devices) 3) etc.
Please reconsider the on-hold @ThePhoton. It was a real electronic questions.

Answer (score 6):

No. They're not USB compliant.

They're not even allowed to carry the USB logo.

Comment: Op did not ask about compliance.

Comment: @Passerby, If not compliant, they shouldn't have the logo. Without the logo (or with an alternate logo) they could be visually distinguished from compliant cables. And how to visually distinguish these cables is a large part of OP's question.

Comment: Arguably they are not a "USB cable". They may be a semi-functional counterfeit if they bear the logo.

Answer (score 6):

One reason to omit the data lines is to make a "charge only" cable.  Using such a cable when charging your devices on a public USB port or charging via an unknown computer assures that no hacking attempts may be made through the USB port while the device is charging.

There are [devices](http://syncstop.com/) that are marketed as "USB condoms" to provide the same function.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO. There is no electronic reason. Just cost.

Never underestimate cost... If it only saves 5¢, when you sell a million of them, that's $50,000 you didn't need to spend.

Yes it can be irritating, but a lot less irritating that the former state of the art of having a box full of wall warts, all different voltages and AC and DC with different jack plug configurations on each, and never the one you needed.

Though, you are right, it would be nice if they changed the symbol on the power ones so you could tell by looking. Though as someone else mentioned, it should not have the logo if it is not a full USB cable.

**ADDITION:** There may also be a limiting liability reason. The manufacturer may not want the headache of dealing with accepting the signals from whatever the cable is attached to.

i.e. Complaint calls of.. "When I plugged your gizmo into the port on my computer, the screen went blank and smoke came out..." or "After I used your cable to recharge the gizmo, my USB port will no longer talk to my hard drive.."